# Combobox in Dropdown List mode - making list item height different from combo-box item height?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to implement a combobox (in drop-down list mode), where the items in the drop-down list are 64 in height, but where the dropdown list item displays itself at normal height.  The use case here is a list containing file names with an image thumbnail next to it.  I want the ordinary display to be normal height with a small thumbnail, but much larger thumbnails in the associated drop-down list.

When I've tried modifying the item height, the entire combobox is set to accommodate it, not just the drop-down list (entirely reasonably I suppose).

Is this possible?

Thanks for any tips.

Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to make the Combobox owner drawn and use the Measure event.
The Event passes the MeasureItemEventArgs which includes the index to the item being drawn.

Here is a sample from Microsoft's documentation [Combobox.Measure event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.measureitem%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Trouble is, I can't see a way in Measure to distinguish between the ComboBox drawing its currently selected item (the one that appears in the combobox line, which I want to be smaller) and that same item in the drop-down list.  I want all items in the list to be large and the combobox itself to be normal height.

Comment: Erg... I'm a dumbass.  It works.  The measure event is the correct event to use as it measures the list items only.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the OwnerDraw mode? This example shows an example with a custom height separator item, but i guess you could apply the same principle to all items in the combo-box..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/26/456977.aspx

Comment: Okey. Glad to hear it worked out for you. Your post didn't mention OwnerDraw so i thought it was worthwhile to point it out. Also, the example is good :)